# Using :after to add a background image but no content

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, insertafter

I have a button that uses a graphic and has rounded corners.

In order to make the button CSS reusable, and able to accommodate any length text whilst still keeping the round corners, I'd like to use `:after` to add the end rounded corner after the main button (thus the first image/text can grow and the rounded corner will always be tacked on the end.)

Managed to get the `:after` working when I add content (e.g the words 'test' and some background colours) but cannot get it to work when there is no content on the styling. I just need the background image and that's it.

[JSFiddle with the buttons.](http://jsfiddle.net/s7KCv/) You can see the `:after` code but for some reason this doesn't display.

```
#wizard-nav .paging:after
{ 
background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/GDJgl.png");
height:22px;
width:7px;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add `content: '';` to your `:after` selector?

Comment: @JanHančič I did try that, and also tried added #&nbsp; to the content to see what happened. It seems to ignore it still, no content added unless I physically write something such as TEST. See: http://jsfiddle.net/s7KCv/2/

Comment: it displays but you wrote it with white on white.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut What do you mean? The orange image is: http://i.imgur.com/GDJgl.png, that is all that needs to be appended to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-selectors you need to set a value to `content`.

Pseudo elements are also inline elements, so if you want to define a height or width then you must display it as a `block` element.

For example:

```
#wizard-nav .paging::after {
    content: "";
    display: block; 
    background-image:url("http://i.imgur.com/GDJgl.png");
    height:22px;
    width:7px;
}
```

**Working example: http://tinkerbin.com/GSO0HpD2**

Comment: Perfect, so `content` is always required when using `:after` - I figured as much. Any reasoning behind why?

Comment: @Francesca: It's useful to be able to control when you want to display the `:after` pseudo-element and when you don't want to depending on the element you apply it to. (You can force it not to display by either not setting `content` at all, or setting `content: none` which it defaults to for pseudo-elements.)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content << in support of @BoltClock's comment (potential content values and their meanings)

Answer (score -1):

You have an alternative for your background-image. You can generate it for example with http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and than applu some border-radius, as much as you like and border, and you have the same effect more quickly than working around a background-image like this. For example:

```
border:red 1px solid;
border-radius:10px;
```

And by the way - they didn't appear because of your background-image. Take down your ".
http://jsfiddle.net/WZywh/ here is an example

Comment: I don't want to use border-radius as it's not supported across all browsers.

Comment: @Francesca what do you think happens when the text is too big for the background image you've prepared?

Comment: I've created the background image as much longer than it needs to be realistically. There will be a certain break point where it is too small, but considering that is larger than the main content area of the site, it will never actually grow to that width.

Comment: why not using background-repeat?